# regex matching of numbers and redirecting them to different output files

Tags: python, regex, shell, awk, sed

This is my current log file

**event_1.log**

```
a   0   3.2 1024    1   0   0
a   0   6.4 2048    2   0   0
le  0   9.6 2048    2   0   0
a   0   12.8    2048    2   0   0
le  0   12.8    2048    2   0   0
ll  0   19.6    2048    2   0   0
a   1   19.6    1024    1   0   0
a   1   22.4    3072    3   0   0
d   0   19.2    2048    2   0   0
le  1   22.4    2048    2   0   0
ll  1   22.8    2048    2   0   0
d   1   22.8    1024    1   0   0
a   0   26  2048    2   0   0
```

Based on the second column, i need to create the file name {second_column}.log. I need to extract only the lines which have 
first_column equal to a or d. The others (le and ll) should be skipped.

The following are my expected outputs

**0.log**

```
a   0   3.2 1024    1   0   0
a   0   6.4 2048    2   0   0
a   0   12.8    2048    2   0   0
d   0   19.2    2048    2   0   0
a   0   26  2048    2   0   0
```

**1.log**

```
a   1   19.6    1024    1   0   0
a   1   22.4    3072    3   0   0
d   1   22.8    1024    1   0   0
```

This is what i tried, but I am clearly novice to regex. I am open to other solutions (shell, sed, awk etc).

```
import re

input_file = open("event_1.log", "r")
output_file = open("column2.log", "w") # want this to be the name of the 2nd column  
for line in input_file:
    match_defines = re.match(r'\s*([a-z]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)', line)

    if match_defines.group(1) == 'a':
        newline1= "\ndef %s():\n    return %s" % (match_defines.group(1),match_defines.group(2))
        output_file.write(newline1)

    else:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat event_1.log | grep "^[a|d]" | while read l; do i=`echo $l |awk '{print $2}'`; echo $l >> ${i}.log; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` with a `regex` to check for `a` or `d` in the first column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("event_1.log", header=None)

df[df[1]==1 & (df[0].str.contains('^(a|d)$'))].to_csv('1.log')

#    0  1     2     3  4  5  6
#6   a  1  19.6  1024  1  0  0
#7   a  1  22.4  3072  3  0  0
#11  d  1  22.8  1024  1  0  0

df[(df[1]==0) & (df[0].str.contains('^(a|d)$'))].to_csv('0.log')

#Out[99]:
#    0  1     2     3  4  5  6
#0   a  0   3.2  1024  1  0  0
#1   a  0   6.4  2048  2  0  0
#3   a  0  12.8  2048  2  0  0
#8   d  0  19.2  2048  2  0  0
#12  a  0  26.0  2048  2  0  0
```

**Data:**

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
     0  1     2     3  4  5  6
0    a  0   3.2  1024  1  0  0
1    a  0   6.4  2048  2  0  0
2   le  0   9.6  2048  2  0  0
3    a  0  12.8  2048  2  0  0
4   le  0  12.8  2048  2  0  0
5   ll  0  19.6  2048  2  0  0
6    a  1  19.6  1024  1  0  0
7    a  1  22.4  3072  3  0  0
8    d  0  19.2  2048  2  0  0
9   le  1  22.4  2048  2  0  0
10  ll  1  22.8  2048  2  0  0
11   d  1  22.8  1024  1  0  0
12   a  0  26.0  2048  2  0  0
```

Comment: I am new to pandas. Any ideas, how does redirection work in pandas

Comment: It's really easy, I updated my post: you need to call method `to_csv` on your dataFrame, by passing the filename. (and some other arguments  like header, the separator, etc). Your data will be saved in theses files.
By the way it is very compact and neat compare to the input_file / output_file going through open/close process.

Comment: Thanks. I get the follwoing error, when i run the above. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_table' .

Comment: sorry it was a silly error with the naming of my file. But still I am unable to run your code. It raises a KeyError: 'no item named 1' on line 5

Comment: `df` is read correctly? do you have the same `df` format as I put in the data section (maybe the header, eg name of columns differ so you should adapt your code in this case - on my side I wrote `df[0]` since my first column is named `0`).

Comment: due to module requirements, I cannot modify the data file. But I shall give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I do not ask you to modify the data file!! but to check after reading your file and obtaining a dataframe what are your column names ... I guess this question is not very difficult ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107158/discussion-between-user2532296-and-colonel-beauvel).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open("event_1.log") as f,open("0.log","w+") as f0, open("1.log","w+") as f1:
    for line in f:
        result1=re.findall(r"^[ad]\s+0\s.*$",line,re.S)
        result2=re.findall(r"^[ad]\s+1\s.*$",line,re.S)
        if result1:
            f0.writelines(result1)
        if result2:
            print(result2)
            f1.writelines(result2)
```

or:

```
with open("event_1.log") as f,open("0.log","w+") as f0, open("1.log","w+") as f1:
    for line in f:
        sl=line.split()
        result0=sl[1]=="0" and (sl[0]=="a" or sl[0]=="d")
        result1=sl[1]=="1" and (sl[0]=="a" or sl[0]=="d")
        if result0:
            f0.write(line)
            print(line)
        if result1:
            f1.write(line)
```

list comprehension:

```
with open("event_1.log") as f,open("0.log","w+") as f0, open("1.log","w+") as f1:
    isad=lambda x:x.split()[0] in ['a','d'] and x.split()[1] in ['0','1']
    [f0.write(r) if r.split()[1]=='0' else f1.write(r) for r in f if isad(r)]
```